# Does running a multi-threaded Emscripten app in the browser require net access when starting a new thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, emscripten

I have a JavaScript+WASM app. The WASM is written in C++, and multi-threaded, built with the -pthread option. It works as expected. But one idea with the app is that, after the app has started and is in a steady state, the network connection can drop and the app should just keep working. I have kinda assumed that of course that will work, why would anything need to be re-downloaded from the web server once things are running.

But now when I then actually try to verify that this indeed is so, to my disappointment I see that after disconnecting the machine from the net, whenever a new thread is to be created, the Emscripten code wants to GET the foo.js and/or foo.worker.js files anew from the web server. Is this a correct understanding? Could this be worked around somehow?

Comment: I know nothing about wasm, but I guess that your threads are implemented via web workers. Every time a new worker is created, a request is sent for the worker file. You can cache files offline with [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)